# Can email ID received from Google OpenID login be considered unique over time?

Tags: authentication, openid, google-openid

I am using Google OpenID for login to my website. I am using it through Tornado's built-in auth library. I retrieve email ID, first name, last name and name from the openID data. My question is can I use email ID retrieved in this way to remain unique over time - *including its case*? For e.g. Is it possible that a user may have email ID `John.Doe@gmail.com` today, but in future it may be `john.doe@gmail.com`? I cannot find any other field in the returned OpenID data that I can assume unique for a given user.

**Update** Maybe I should also add that I was hosting my website on Google App Engine before and was using its built-in login. When I migrated to Tornado based implementation, I used email ID from the old logins as the unique identifier of the users. In most of the cases that seems to have work, but recently I ran into a case where the user's email ID returned from OpenID was different from his email ID from GAE version only in case. Therefore I am trying to understand how this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an email address, you shouldn't consider case, as for normal email case is unimportant. So, you should be able to consider that unique in a case insensitive test.